# How do I fix the generator for Resource.Designer.fs so that it escapes language keywords?

Tags: f#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Create a blank Android app from the F# template in Visual Studio.

Add the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package.

Build the project.

The build fails because of this line in `Resource.Designer.fs`:

```
static member end = 2131165212
```

Because `end` is a keyword in F#, the error reads "Unexpected keyword 'end' in member definition".

There is a fix: you can replace `end` as follows:

```
static member ``end`` = 2131165212
```

However, `Resource.Designer.fs` is a generated file, so I have to keep doing this.

How is this file generated? How would I go about making a pull request to fix this bug?